# How to play .mp4 video on videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

just want to know how to play a .mp4 video on videoview.
I got a tutorial from http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-video-formats-in-android-using-videoview/28299 and my app is not working.

I followed everything. i named my video "video.mp4".
I used this code to find the path of a specific video:

```
video_player_view.setVideoPath(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "video.mp4");
```

I even made a "raw" folder and placed the video there. I used `@raw/video.mp4` for it.

Can you guys help me out please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `"/video.mp4"` instead of `"video.mp4"` for Video name and please explain more which problem you are getting

Comment: i can't play the video.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the video to the videoview with setVideoURI().

```
vidVwYourView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.your_video));
```

Just make sure 'your_video.mp4' is stored in your res/raw/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. In may case, I remove video file extension and it works. So try with **"video"** instead of **"video.mp4"**